# Executar procedure oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Criei essa procedure mas não consigo executar.
Tenho o seguinte erro ao tentar o Execute:

> PLS-00306: número incorreto de tipos de argumentos na chamada para 'SP_CARTAO'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_CARTAO
(
   P_ID IN INT ,
   P_ID_CARTAO OUT INT
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT ID_CARTAO INTO P_ID_CARTAO
  from log_cartao
  where log_cartao.id_cartao = P_ID;
END;

EXECUTE SP_CARTAO(1);
```

Answer (score 5):

A procedure espera 2 parâmetros mas você está passando só um parâmetro pra ela.

Para passar um parâmetro de saída para uma stored procedure Oracle, você pode fazer assim:

```
declare
P_ID_CARTAO number;
begin
EXECUTE SP_CARTAO(1, P_ID_CARTAO);
-- aqui, a variável P_ID_CARTAO terá o valor que foi setado pela stored procedure
end;
```